# How to make the "Make New Sticky Note" shortcut work?

Tags: keyboard, catalina, shortcut

In 10.15 System Preferences>Keyboard>Shortcuts>Services there is a shortcut for "Make New Sticky Note" that can be enabled. 
However, enabling it and trying the shortcut results in no action. I hoped/understood it was a shortcut to create a new sticky new from anywhere.